# Django - customised validation error

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-validation

I am trying to add a customised validation as part of my form.

I am trying to trip the customised validation when the voluntary_date_display_type is a specified number. However, when I run the following code, the voluntary_date_display_type value is **None** and I am expecting a number/digit.

I have read the django docs on [form field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/validation/), but I cannot see my error.

Currently only the final else condition is triggered as the value is None.

Can someone point out what I have done wrong?

Here is the code from my forms.py file:

```
class Meta:
    model = VoluntaryDetails

    fields = (
        .......
        'voluntary_date_display_type',
        .......
    )

def clean_voluntary_finish_date(self):

    voluntary_display_type = self.cleaned_data.get('voluntary_display_type')
    voluntary_start_date = self.cleaned_data.get('voluntary_start_date')
    voluntary_finish_date = self.cleaned_data.get('voluntary_finish_date')
    voluntary_date_display_type = self.cleaned_data.get('voluntary_date_display_type')

    if voluntary_display_type == 0:
        if voluntary_finish_date is not None and voluntary_start_date is not None:
            if voluntary_start_date > voluntary_finish_date:
                if voluntary_date_display_type == 2 or voluntary_date_display_type == 3:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("To Date must be after the From Date."))
                elif voluntary_date_display_type == 4 or voluntary_date_display_type == 5:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("Finish Date must be after the Start Date."))
                elif voluntary_date_display_type == 6 or voluntary_date_display_type == 7:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("End Date must be after the Begin Date."))
                elif voluntary_date_display_type == 8:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("This Date must be after the other Date."))
                elif voluntary_date_display_type == 9 or voluntary_date_display_type == 10:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("This Duration date must be after the other Duration date."))
                else:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(_("Completion Date must be after the Commencement Date."))

    return voluntary_finish_date
```

Answer (score 1):

`clean_voluntary_finish_date` is only called when that particular field is validated, so others may not yet be "cleaned". This means that when you use `self.cleaned_data.get('voluntary_date_display_type')`, that field is not cleaned yet, so there is no key in `cleaned_data`, and the `.get()` method will return `None`.

You need to use the normal `clean()` method when validation depends on more than one field; as stated in the django forms [reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other) under *"Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other"*:

> Suppose we add another requirement to our contact form: if the
>   cc_myself field is True, the subject must contain the word "help". We
>   are performing validation on more than one field at a time, so the
>   form’s clean() method is a good spot to do this. **Notice that we are
>   talking about the clean() method on the form here, whereas earlier we
>   were writing a clean() method on a field.** It’s important to keep the
>   field and form difference clear when working out where to validate
>   things. Fields are single data points, forms are a collection of
>   fields.
>
> **By the time the form’s clean() method is called, all the individual
>   field clean methods will have been run (the previous two sections), so
>   self.cleaned_data will be populated with any data that has survived so
>   far. So you also need to remember to allow for the fact that the
>   fields you are wanting to validate might not have survived the initial
>   individual field checks.**

All you have to do is:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(YourFormClassName, self).clean()
    # copy and paste the rest of your code here
    return cleaned_data # this is not required as of django 1.7
```